# Permissions in ASP.Net Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm using Master page in my website. When the user logged in, the ASP menu button of the master page should be enabled or disabled according to the user permission. How can I do this?

Comment: Button is in Master Page...... I already disabled that particular button.. When the user is enabled for that particulart feature, then that button should be enabled for him in the master page

Comment: Thank U! I found the solution for it..... 
Code:
Menu1.Items[3].Enabled=False

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public method in the code behind of your master page which will load user permissions and enable or disable menu button.

In Master Page code behind.

```
Public void EnableMenuBar() {
 //.... Load user permissions here.
 //.... here make menu bar enable or disable. 
}
```

Then make this call in the end of your default constructor for your master page.

Answer (score 0):

In master page Page_Load event check if user logged in then enable or disable menu button
according to the user permission.

Comment: Is there 'Enabled' property for that menu Button? If yes then set Enabled=true or Enabled=false
Put the checking in Page_Load event under if(!IsPostback)
{
}

Answer (score 0):

Thank U Everybody! 
I found the solution for it..... Code: Menu1.Items[3].Enabled=False